# Button must be clicked twice for second event to happen vb

Tags: vb.net

I have a program which generates a password when a button is clicked. The code for the button is as follows:

```
Private Sub generate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles generate.Click
    Module1.firstname = firstnameb.Text
    Module1.surname = secondnameb.Text
    Module1.colour = colourb.Text
    Module1.dob = dobb.Text
    Module1.dod = dodb.Text
    Module1.password = ((Mid$(Module1.firstname, 1, 1)) & (Mid$(Module1.surname, 1, 1)) & (Mid$(Module1.colour, 1, 1)) & (Mid$(Module1.dob, 1, 1)) & (Mid$(Module1.dod, 1, 1)))

    Timer1.Start()
    If ProgressBar1.Value < 100 Then
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    ElseIf ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        passwordresultb.Text = Module1.password

    End If


End Sub
```

However, I have to press the button twice: once for the progress bar and a second time for the password to come in a box.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess `ProgressBar1.Value` is `0` when you start your application and `ProgressBar1.Maximum` is `1`?

Comment: The `ProgressBar1.Value` is set to `10`

Comment: Just curious - did you try throwing the Progress bar code in a different sub and simply calling it from this sub?

Comment: What's `ProgressBar1.Maximum`?

Comment: No, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please include the code for Timer1's Tick event.

Comment: `Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
        If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            passwordresultb.Text = Module1.password
        End If

    End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

You need to move that whole If block inside the timer's `Tick` event.

Comment: Note that this is probably not enough if the application runs under Vista/Windows 7 due to the animation of the progress bar. The text will be displayed before the animation ends.

Comment: This is inside the button's click event and runs under windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

When you click your button, this method will be called once. If the ProgressBar.Value is less than 100, it gets incremented. Otherwise, the text box gets updated with the password. Only one of these will happen per call, since you use the If..ElseIf pattern.

Your intentions are not very clear given the provided code. I can't tell how you are using the progress bar, or what for. But the root of your problem is the If..ElseIf statement. If you simply want the password to show in the text box when the button is clicked, remove the ProgressBar bit and just update the textbox.

If you want your progress bar to update to 'maximum' before displaying the password, try this (My VB is a little rusty... but this should be it):

```
While ProgressBar1.Value < ProgressBar1.MaximumValue
    ProgressBar.Value += 1
End While

passwordresultb.Text = Module1.password
```

Comment: I am trying to make a password generator program where the progress bar looks like it is generating the password then the password appears